# ...can you say that you won’t and haven’t sold Pegasus to [ellipsis]

Tags: grammar, ellipses, auxiliary-verbs

Is this kind of elliptical construction used widely?

> SHALEV: I’m not gonna talk  about specific customer.
>
> LESLEY: But can you say that ***you won’t and haven’t sold*** Pegasus to a country that is known to violate human rights and  imprison journalists and go after activists?
>
> SHALEV: I only say that we are selling  Pegasus in order to prevent crime and terror.
>
> — [CBS interview](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/interview-with-ceo-of-nso-group-israeli-spyware-maker-on-fighting-terror-khashoggi-murder-and-saudi-arabia-60-minutes/)

Comment: If you're really asking how common this construction is, then a [simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you+won%27t+and+haven%27t%22&oq=%22you+won%27t+and+haven%27t%22&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQABiiBDIHCAIQABiiBNIBCTEwODU1ajBqMagCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#ip=1) would show that.

Answer (score 1):

No. A deletion must involve a word that appears elsewhere in the same form.

*They didn't sell and won't sell Pegasus to a country that is known to violate human rights*

-→

*They didn't and won't sell Pegasus to a country that is known to violate human rights*

But

*They haven't sold and won't sell Pegasus to a country that is known to violate human rights*

-/→

**They haven't and won't sell Pegasus to a country that is known to violate human rights*.

Comment: In the same form? What about "They haven't played the piano and are not." ?

Comment: In the first two sentences above, the lexeme 'sell' appears twice as the base form in the undeleted variant, licensing the deletion of the second 'sell'. But in the second sentence, 'sell' appears as the past participle 'sold' as well as the base form in the undeleted sentence, rendering the deletion ungrammatical.

Comment: I think there's a significant *but fairly recent* US/UK usage split here. Since WW2, [BrE has become ***more*** tolerant of "mixed tense" combinations](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=haven%27t+and+won%27t&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=10) while [AmE has become ***less*** tolerant.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=haven%27t+and+won%27t&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=10) As a Brit, I have absolutely no problem with *I haven't and won't do it* - and I think *I haven't **done** and wont do it* is just "fastidious".

Comment: @FF Use a 'mixed tense combination'? I'm a Brit, and I haven't done it and won't do it.

Answer (score 1):

The usual sequence is ***have not and will not** [infinitive verb]*, rather than ***won't and haven't** [past tense verb]*. It's not usually *contracted* either, since this construction is usually used *emphatically*, and contractions tend to be somewhat less than emphatic.

Probably the preferred sequence is at least partly because the "normal" version is "temporally consistent", in that it advances from from Past to Future, rather than the other way around.

But regardless of which order you present the verbs, if the precise *syntax* of the two elements isn't identical in such "verb pair" constructions, whatever follows should be consistent with the *second* element. So you could reasonably say any of...

> 1: *I haven't and won't speak to anyone else*
> 2: *I won't and haven't spoken to anyone else*
> 3: *I haven't and won't ask anyone else*

...where the "deleted" element before *"**and**"* is ***spoken to*** in #1, ***speak to*** in #2, and ***asked*** in #3. It's irrelevant that the precise format (tense + preposition) of the deleted element is slightly different to the actual verb (and preposition, if appropriate) that comes *after* *"**and**"*.

---

TL;DR: The cited text does indeed feature "ellipsis" ("deletion" of "predictable / repeated" elements). But the *specific* example is relatively unusual, because of the sequence of the two verb tenses.